# How to configure .emacs to enable "C-v" to move cursor half window height

Tags: emacs, lisp

I'm trying to make it so that C-v binds to a function where it moves the cursor half the window-height down, any help on this?

Comment: Do you really want to use the window _width_ when deciding how much to move up or down? It seems like height would be more relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's what you want to do, this will do it:

```
(global-set-key [(control ?v)]
 (lambda () (interactive (next-line (/ (window-height (selected-window)) 2)))))
```

Comment: what should I do for scroll up?

Comment: @alper Replacing `next-line` with `previous-line` should work.

Comment: I replace it but now cursor goes to top of the page and later goes half page up, on `next-line` cursor was always remain on the center

Comment: Gor next-line I have having `‘next-line’ is for interactive use only; use ‘forward-line’ instead.` warning message , what should I do?

Comment: @alper What version of Emacs are you using? The code from the answer works for me in Emacs 27.1 without errors or warnings.

Comment: I was using gccEmac which is `GNU Emacs 28.0.50`

Comment: @alper I don't have access to that version yet. Maybe you could report to them as a bug that this code no longer works. They might also be able to provide a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found: use View.el, which should be available by default (it was for me at least). Hinted at: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HalfScrolling

Then, do some keybinding to change the default behaviour. My Emacs init files now contain:

```
;; Scroll only half-pages.
(require 'view)
(global-set-key "\C-v"   'View-scroll-half-page-forward)
(global-set-key "\M-v"   'View-scroll-half-page-backward)
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HalfScrolling:

> By default Emacs scrolls nearly full screenfuls with scroll-up and scroll-down. I personally would like it to scroll half a page at a time, but unfortunately haven’t been able to figure out how to do it cleanly.
>
> There is a next-screen-context-lines variable which controls how many lines of continuity should be preserved when scrolling by screenfuls. The problem at hand could be solved by setting this variable to window-height/2, but obviously it should be calculated every time the next-screen-context-lines is used because window-height is not constant.
>
> The only working solution I came up with is the following sucky hack. It’s still better than nothing, so here it comes:

```
(defun window-half-height ()
  (max 1 (/ (1- (window-height (selected-window))) 2)))

(defun scroll-up-half ()
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up (window-half-height)))

(defun scroll-down-half ()         
  (interactive)                    
  (scroll-down (window-half-height)))

(global-set-key [next] 'scroll-up-half)
(global-set-key [prior] 'scroll-down-half)
```

You should be able to change that `global-set-key` to use `"\C-v"` and get what you want.
A few other solutions to the same problem are on that page, check it out.

Comment: Currently that is what I have, but it doesn't just move the cursor but also sets it so that the cursor is at the top of the screen, even if it moves half height up/down. is there a way to get around that

Comment: Ah, so you don't really want scroll. You want to move cursor, as if you just pressed the down arrow height/2 times? May sub `next-line` for `scroll-down` ?